# amcharts irregular grid Axis

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I need to stack columns with different width inline.
Maybe need change x grid to irregular.
How remove distance between columns with different `columnWidth` ?
Or how make columns position one by one without empty places ?

Photo,
[image]

Demo below:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "marginRight": 70,
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits1": 3025,
    "color": "#FF0F00"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits2": 1882,
    "color": "#FF6600"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits3": 1809,
    "color": "#FF9E01"
  }, ],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Visitors from country"
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits1",
    "columnWidth":0.8
  },
  {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits2",
    "columnWidth":0.2
  },
  {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits3",
    "columnWidth":0.5
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "labelRotation": 45
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.amcharts-export-menu-top-right {
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to keep 1 graph and use [widthField](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#widthField) in your `CategoryAxis` to determine the columns width.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "marginRight": 70,
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 3025,
    "color": "#FF0F00",
    "width": 0.8
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "color": "#FF6600",
    "width": 0.2
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "color": "#FF9E01",
    "width": 0.5
  }, ],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Visitors from country"
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "labelRotation": 45,
    "widthField": "width"
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.amcharts-export-menu-top-right {
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```